# Why does call of IL generated method throw InvalidProgramException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, reflection.emit

I'm generating Web API controllers at runtime (.Net Core 3.0). What I have is a generic base controller from which I inherit the generated controller and when setting up the http actions I want to call a method from the base class and return its value. When I call /api/Foo/1 an InvalidProgramException is being raised.

**EDIT**: I simplified the code and added a running example (see [Working Example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yihu08nfxobj836/FooApp.zip?dl=0)).

What I want to achieve:

```
public class FooController : GenericBaseController<Foo, int> {

    [HttpGet]
    public Foo Get(int id){
        return base.DoGet(id);
    }
}
```

What the base controller looks like:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public abstract class GenericBaseController<T, TId> : ControllerBase {

    protected T DoGet(TId id)
    { 
        return default;
    }
}
```

What the type builder code setting up the method looks like:

```
        MethodBuilder builder = tb.DefineMethod("Get", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Final, modelType, new Type[] {typeof(int)});

        builder.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "id");

        ConstructorInfo httpCtorInfo = typeof(HttpGetAttribute).GetConstructors().First();
        CustomAttributeBuilder httpAttrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(httpCtorInfo, new object[0]);
        builder.SetCustomAttribute(httpAttrBuilder);

        ILGenerator emitter = builder.GetILGenerator();

        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);

        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); 
        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); 

        MethodInfo baseMethod = baseCrudController.GetMethod("DoGet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseMethod);

        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, 0011);
        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);

        emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I tried to rebuild from what I got as I OpCodes using an ilreader found here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body

```
0000 : nop 
0001 : ldarg.0 
0002 : ldarg.1 
0003 : call instance FooProject.Controllers.GenericBaseController`1[System.Int32]::DoGet() 
0008 : stloc.0 
0009 : br.s 0011 
0011 : ldloc.0 
0012 : ret
```

Comment: `public T Get(TId id)` -- did you mean `public Foo Get(int id)`?

Comment: @canton7: You're right, I updated the post.

Comment: There are also many problems with your code which prevent it from compiling. Please post a [mcve] which people can run, without having to fix syntax and type errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to massage your code quite a bit to get it to compile and run. Once I did this, it ran perfectly, so I'm not sure which part of my massaging fixed the problem you had. The changes I made:

1. When you define your `tb` (by calling `DefineType`), you need to make sure that it inherits from `baseCrudController`. Since you declare `baseCrudController` *later*, I'm not convinced you were doing this. But it's hard to say, because this code isn't in your question
2. In your call to `tb.DefineMethod`, strings in C# need double quotes, not single quotes
3. In that same call, you need `typeof(Foo), new[] { typeof(int) }` not `typeof(Foo), typeof(int)`, as you need to pass an array of parameter types
4. You need to use `typeof(HttpGetAttribute)`, not `typeof(HttpGet)`
5. `HttpGetAttribute` has multiple constructors, and you can't rely on the order that they're returned in. Explicitly specify that you want the parameterless constructor
6. You don't need the `nops`, and you don't need the `stloc`/`ldloc` after the `call`. Those are only added in Debug builds to help the debugger
7. In fact, since you haven't declared a local slot `0`, the `stloc.0` and `ldloc.0` are invalid. When you're using `System.Reflection.Emit`, if you need to store a value into a local slot, use a `LocalBuilder` and don't explicitly address the slots by number.
8. When you call the base method, its name is `"DoGet"` and not `"GetInBase"`

Make all of those changes and you get this, which works:

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("Test");
var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Test");
Type baseCrudController = typeof(GenericBaseController<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Foo), typeof(int));
var tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType("FooController", TypeAttributes.Public, baseCrudController);

MethodBuilder builder = tb.DefineMethod("Get", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.NewSlot | MethodAttributes.Final, typeof(Foo), new[] { typeof(int) });

ConstructorInfo httpCtorInfo = typeof(HttpGetAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
CustomAttributeBuilder httpAttrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(httpCtorInfo, new object[0]);
builder.SetCustomAttribute(httpAttrBuilder);

ILGenerator emitter = builder.GetILGenerator();

emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

MethodInfo baseTypeMethod = baseCrudController.GetMethod("DoGet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Call, baseTypeMethod);

emitter.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Test
var resultType = tb.CreateType();
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(resultType);
var result = resultType.GetMethod("Get").Invoke(instance, new object[] { 3 });
```

Comment: Thank you! I added a complete reproducing example to the post. For asking the question I tried to strip down the real code but obiously made some mistakes... In fact 7 stloc was the one thing breaking the code

Comment: @Stefan Great! For future, it's really important that you code in your question actually represents your problem. It's great to try and simplify your problem as much as possible, but you *must* make sure that you can actually run it!

Comment: Hm one strange thing is that calling the method as you did in your test works as expected. Try getting swagger documentation breaks with an error and trying to call /api/foo/get?id=1 produces "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'modelName') - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(ActionContext actionContext, IValueProvider valueProvider, ModelMetadata metadata, BindingInfo bindingInfo, string modelName)". Do you have any Idea what is missing?

Comment: @Stefan I'm afraid that's beyond my experience - I don't do much with Web API, so I don't know how it behaves around dynamically-generated controllers.

Comment: Just found it out myself so I leave it here and update my post: as mvc routing tries to autobind parameters it obviously can't find any parameter with the name "Id" as I originally did not set parameter name anywhere. It is required to use builder.DefineParameter...